# Como fazer isso usando @RenderBody do Asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Todas as telas do meu sistema são Views e são rendenizadas no @RenderBody no _Layout principal

Eu gostaria de mudar meu layout e fazer com que ele fique assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então, básicamente é como eu expliquei na imagem, Clica no Menu vai rendenizar ali, e após clicar no submenu lateral rendenizar novamente ali, sem remover o menu

O que eu pensei, em criar uma partial com o menu, Mas aí eu teria que adicionar ela em todas as minhas Views...

PartialMenuCadastro -> Itens do menu...

Aí coloca-las na listagem de cliente, na criação, na edição, etc, etc no dashboard...

Não sei se é correto isso, e não me parece muito elegante...

Pensei também, em rendenizar usando Ajax, mas aí eu teria que mudar todas as minhas views para partial e não sei se seria correto isso também...

Alguém tem alguma ideia para me dar?

Comment: Basta que todas as suas Views utilizem a mesma view Layout, e você obterá o resultado desejado.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Uma solução para usar `Ajax`, sem precisar mudar todas suas `Views` para `PartialViews`, seria fazer uma requisição `Ajax` na sua `Action` e então pegar só o `RenderBody` gerado dessa `View`.

Um exemplo para ficar mais claro:

***_Layout***

```
(...)
<div id="Conteudo">
    @RenderBody()
</div>
(...)
```

Então na sua `View`:

```
<a onclick="Open('Modulo/Index')">Clique aqui</a>
<div id="Conteudo2">
</div>

<script>
    function Open(url) {
        url = '@Url.Content("~/")' + url;
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (response) {
                $('#Conteudo2').html($(response).find('#Conteudo'));
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Ocorreu um erro!');
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Acho AJAX pouco interessante para esta solução.

Me parece que este o conteúdo deste seu menu lateral está diretamente relacionado ao link acesso no menu superior. Você pode passar essa lista de links do menu lateral dinamicamente (por ViewBag ou algo parecido) e renderizar normalmente no _Layout.

Em _Layout:

```
<div class="conteudo">
    <div class="menulateral">
        @foreach(var item in ViewBag.LinksFromMenuSuperior) {
            <a href="@item.Link">@item.Titulo</a>
        }
    </div>
    <div>
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</div>
```

Você também pode utilizar @Section {} e @RenderSection(), que talvez você não conheça por não ter comentado como opção, mas vale uma consulta, infelizmente ele (nesta solução) se comportaria muito como a @PartialView(), pois você também terá que alterar as páginas.

Comment: estou com mesmo problema, não entendi a sua solução consegue explicar com mais detalhes?

Comment: @Zica, na verdade o problema do usuário acima é referente a renderizar uma pedaço da página sem ter que chamar em todas as outras. O ASP .Net MVC resolve isso utilizando uma página mestre, por padrão "_Layout.cshtml", o que eu sugiro é fazer a chamada desta página auxiliar (menu lateral) nesta página mestre, evitando a chamada em todas as outras. Uma alternativa (porém recomendo a chamada de uma página auxiliar na página mestre) que eu sugeri também é construir a página auxiliar (menu lateral) diretamente na página mestre.