# Atualizar menu via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quando clicava no item do menu da minha aplicação ela sempre atualizava a página, estou alterando para atualizar via ajax as páginas contudo estou com dificuldades em relação a funções com nomes baseado no evento de classes, exemplo a função delete quando eu clico é chamada a função da página anterior e da página atual. Teria como remover tudo da página anterior?
Exemplo: Clico em página de cidade e após clico na pagina Pais, a função Open carrega a index, quando eu clico no botão delete é chamado 2 vezes, sendo a index de cidade nao está mais sendo demonstrada.

```js
function Open(url, descricao) {
       // event.preventDefault();
        url = '@Url.Content("~/")' + url;
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (response) {
                console.log("s");
                $('#principal').html($(response).find('#Conteudo2'));
                window.history.pushState("object or string", descricao, url);

            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Ocorreu um erro!');
            }
        });
    }
    
    $(document).on("click", ".btn-delete", function () {
            var link = $(this).attr("id");
            var removeItemEl = $(this);

            confirm("Você tem certeza que deseja excluir o pais registro?",

                function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "Pais/delete",
                        data: {
                            id: link
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            removeItemEl.closest("tr").remove();
                        },
                        error: function (data) {
                            alert("O País já foi utilizado, não é possível deletar o registro!");
                        }
                    })
                }

                , "Confirmação de exclusão");


        });
```

Comment: Ele chama o evento da página anterior, exemplo cliquei na tela e cidade e após na tela de Pais a rotina chama o evento das 2 telas. @dvd

Comment: Não eu carrego primeiro uma tela e no onclic eu chamo o metodo open que carrega a segunda tela, após se eu interagir com o botão delete é chamado 2 vezes a função @dvd

Comment: @dvd a tela são as index.

Comment: @dvd sim cada uma index diferente e funções diferente.

Comment: @dvd isso mesmo

Comment: @dvd funcionou assim, contudo eu tenho mais eventos com esse problema, então preciso fazer isso pra todos? Tem alguma forma de anular todos? Ou é melhor criar eventos com nomes unicos para cada index?

Comment: Fecho obrigado @dvd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como você está carregando páginas externas que vêm com os mesmos eventos que já existem, você pode cancelar os eventos atuais antes de carregar o novo conteúdo, usando o método `.off()` do jQuery.

Você pode cancelar um evento para um seletor específico:

```
$(document).off("click", ".btn-delete");
```

Ou pode cancelar todos:

```
$(document).off();
```

Mais sobre o método `.off()` na **[documentação oficial](http://api.jquery.com/off/)**.

Comment: uma dúvida quando uso o comando off ele bloqueia o evento de abertura do menu,uso o data-toggle dentro da tag <a> para ligar com a tag <ul>.

Sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: @Zica Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: obrigado funcionou, uma pergunta você considera uma boa prática fazer atualização assim? Porque tem que lembrar pra adicionar as classe para remover, o que pode ser um problema.
Segui esse post para fazer  essa ideá
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31954/como-fazer-isso-usando-renderbody-do-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Acho que cada página que vc carrega deve ter suas próprias funções. Pode até usar a mesma classe .btn-delete, mas deveria ter um outro seletor que diferenciasse um do outro. Por exemplo, uma div que "abriga" o botão com outra classe ou id diferente assim não teria esse problema.